# Array/tabular env. showing fractions directly in display mode and correctly spaced?

Tags: tables, arrays, fractions, displaystyle

In my Latex documents I usually include arrays and tables with fraction that always get crushed to their inline form, giving an unpleasant result. I know I could solve the issue by switching every \frac to \dfrac and adjusting the vertical spaces between lines manually, but I was wondering if there's a quicker and smarter way to solve this. I checked the array package but I didn't seem to find anything about this issue.

Here's a MWE of an array crushing fractions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{x}}=m \dot{x}\quad \frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{x}}\right)=m \ddot{x}\quad \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=0 \\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{y}}=m \dot{y}\quad \frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{y}}\right)=m \ddot{y}\quad \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}=0 \\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{z}}=m \dot{z}\quad \frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{z}}\right)=m \ddot{z}\quad \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}=0
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
What I'm looking for (not sure it exists) is an environment, or a "declaration" valid through the whole environment, switching every math element to \displastyle, just like the \dcases environment for the regular \cases one.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal working example? Are there anything else in the cells besides math? Maybe the `mode=dmath` from the tabularray package might be handy.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sure, I just edited the question with a MWE (sorry I'm new to the site), usually there's nothing else in them except for math. I'll start looking the math mode up. How does it work if I can ask?

Comment: The problem with making all math to use display style automatically is that this will result in poor line spacing in case you happen to have some inline math in your text. If you want display styles for tables etc., you should only use diplsay style and not for your whole document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use environments from the `tabularray` package for your arrays and tables, you can use `mode=dmath` for the cells which contain math. This will make them show up in display style.

A short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{+array}{
  colspec={X},
  cells={mode=dmath}
}
\frac{1}{2}\\
\end{+array}
\]

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={c},
  cells={mode=dmath}
}
\frac{1}{2}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It does work. I'll have to look the documentation up for all the new features but its going to work. Thanks again!

Comment: @5kywAlker43 You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

well if I understood you question well, you're seeking to produce a table with math expressions, I would do that using `array` environment instead of `tabular` (you don't want to use `$` in every cell, don't you :D), speaking of `\dfrac` and `\frac`, well the `nccmath` package provide medium size fractions which is `\mfrac`, let's give what we've said a shot, and let's create a small integration table (I'm not trying to remind you of calc II don't worry) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, nccmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

    \begin{document}
        \[
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \makecell[l]{\mathbb{R}_+^*}  & x^n  & \mfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+c \\
    \hline
    \mathbb{R}^*    & \mfrac{1}{x} & \ln \vert x\vert +c \\
    \hline
    \mathbb{R}      & e^{\lambda x} & \mfrac{1}{\lambda}e^x+c \\
    \hline
    \mathbb{R}      & \cos(\omega x)  & \mfrac{1}{\omega}\sin(\omega x)+c \\
    \hline
    \mathbb{R}      & \sin(\omega x)  & \mfrac{1}{\omega} \cos(\omega x)+c \\
    \hline
    \end{array}
        \]
    \end{document}
```

Here's the compilation result :

[image]

The code is pretty simple, for more vertical space around cells content you would employ `\setcellgapes` defined in the `makecell` package, there's also a problem of alignment in the first cell, so adding `\makecell[l]{}` will fix the problem.

Anyways I hope this will help you, this is how I usually make tables when all the cells contains mathematical expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll surely use \mfrac and the \array environments suggestion will be useful. I wasn't clear enough while writing the question so I edited it.. but still thanks!